# How do I select unique nodes in XSLT 1.0 using an expression?

Tags: xslt, select, unique

I've seen lots of questions and solutions regarding determining unique nodes in XSLT and succeeded in getting that to work until I needed to evaluate the uniqueness using an expression.

Using this data file:

```
<root>
    <data><field>find me: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword2</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword2</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>find me: keyword2</field></data>
</root>
```

And this transform template:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="data[not(field=preceding-sibling::data/field)]">
        field=<xsl:value-of select="field"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="data[not(substring-after(field,': ')=substring-after(preceding-sibling::data/field,': '))]">
        short_field=<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(field,': ')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following output:

```
field=find me: keyword1
field=find me: keyword2
short_field=keyword1
short_field=keyword2
short_field=keyword2
short_field=keyword2
```

The first `for-each` works as expected but once I process `field` using `substring-after` (because in reality the leading text won't always match), only the first value actually matches. Notice the two extra keyword2 values.

Can anybody explain this and propose a solution? I'm using MSXSL to perform this evaluation.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output would not have the last two lines of what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen lots of questions and solutions regarding determining unique
>   nodes in XSLT

It's too bad you missed all the good ones - i.e. those dealing with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Try it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="field-by-suffix" match="field" use="substring-after(.,': ')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/data/field[count(. | key('field-by-suffix', substring-after(.,': '))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:text>short_field=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,': ')" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following example input:

```
<root>
    <data><field>alpha: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>bravo: keyword2</field></data>
    <data><field>charlie delta: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>echo: keyword2</field></data>
    <data><field>foxtrot: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>golf hotel: keyword1</field></data>
    <data><field>echo: keyword2</field></data>
</root>
```

the result is:

```
short_field=keyword1
short_field=keyword2
```

Comment: I had seen the Muenchian grouping approaches which usually used generate-id. Those seemed overly complicated for my needs. I had also seen keys used, but they all assumed you knew what the actual keys were going to be. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!   

I pondered your solution and I think I understand how it works. In short, you take the union of the current node with the first node returned by the key. If they are the same node, there will only be one node, otherwise there will be two. The results with a count of one are the first node with that key and therefore are distinct.

Comment: @ReeseAnschultz "*the union of the current node with the first node returned by the key. If they are the same node, there will only be one node*" Yes. And it works the same way with generate-id: if my id is the same as the id of the first member of the group, then I am that first member.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(preceding-sibling::data/field,': ')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you will see that in this case it is always getting the same value. In fact if you change the first field to something like `keyword0` you will see that in your second loop you are always comparing to that first node. Also note that it only outputs 6 values when there are 7 in the data, because the first one is empty. The `substring-after` only processes a single node to compare to instead of all `preceding-sibling::` nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It's fairly obvious to me, now, that the first case is comparing a node to a node set generating a new node set. The second case is comparing two strings, the second of which is essential the equivalent to calling string() on the node set which yields the string from the first node.

This leads to the ultimate question, how do I compare the string values of all the nodes, not just the first one?

Comment: The next part depends on if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.